# HTML5 on netbeans 7.3 can not integrate with chrome Netbeans Connector

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, netbeans

I just created an empty HTML5 project and could not run it through the new Chrome netbeans Connector feature. I have added the netbeans connector extension to my chrome browser, but I keep getting this warning "Could not access Url through external browser. Check browser configuration."
I have the latest netbeans version 7.3 and jdk 7u17. Chrome browser Version 25.0.1364.172 m.

Anyone with some suggestions?

Comment: That could be bug http://netbeans.org/projects/web/lists/issues/archive/2012-08/message/59

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error using OpenSUSE 12.3 x86_64.

My solution was this: go to `Netbeans Menu > Tools > Options`. In the `General` tab press `Edit` and then edit the command for Chrome browser to:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Doing this supposed to work but had no effect on my NetBeans. It still tries to run "/opt/google/chrome/chrome". 
Is there a property in config file which we can try to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issues with Netbeans 7.3.1 and Chromium 29.0; editing the "Chrome" browser executable in the "Tools>Options>General" section to point to the "chromium" exec location didn't seem to make a difference at first.

---

Open the ***project properties***, you can further edit the application with which the file will open/execute.  The default **browser** is "Chrome with NetBeans integration".   So far, changing that "**Browser**" field in the
*project* properties to point to the edited **Chrome** exec runs the file in the Chromium browser.  However, I'm not sure how well--if at all--it integrates with NetBeans itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in the embedded browser. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's probably best to file a bug report at http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html. Where/when does the warning appear? If you file a bug, please attach the IDE log and a screenshot of the error. Thanks.